# Inversion of n x n matrix

Tags: matrices

A matrix F is given:
$$
F = [e^{i\frac{2\pi kl}{n}}]_{k,l=0}^{n-1}
$$
Find $$ F^{-1} $$

I know Gaussian method for inverting matrices but I suppose it doesn't apply to  matrices with not given exact n value. Could you tell me what are the methods for inverting matrices like this?

Comment: Maybe, the inverse can be calculated depending on $n$. Then, the limit, if it exists, would be the inverse of the infinite matrix.

Comment: The matrix seems to be $n\times n$, not infinite.

Comment: Of course, edited

Comment: Well, this matrix is the one you use to perform a discrete Fourier transform. The inverse is then, not surprisingly, the one used when performing the inverse Fourier transform. Try to multiply $F$ by its conjugate transpose. You should get a scalar matrix.

Comment: I'd try to write this matrix for small $n$, invert in manually by any known method, and then make a hypothesis on the general form.

Comment: For heaven's sake don't try to find the inverse by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

This is a famous matrix, $1/\sqrt{n}\cdot F$ is unitary. One can check this directly or look at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Orthogonality

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It's a Vandermonde matrix ([link1](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde's_Matrix) and [link2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#The_unitary_DFT)).